# How do I convert dub.sdl into dub.json?

Tags: d, dub

Since MonoD doesn't let me add use dub libraries natively I need to write `dub.json` myself. A good start would be to use an already existing template produced by e.g. `dub init`, but unfortunately this command produces a project that uses a competing `dub.sdl` and for some reason I cannot find any option to tell it to create a `dub.json` instead.

How do I convert a `dub.sdl` into `dub.json` so I can use it with MonoD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by `dub init --help`, there is an option for generating JSON file instead of SDL:

> -f  --format=VALUE
>
> Sets the format to use for the package description file. Possible values: sdl, json

So, try `dub init --format=json`.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot understand how did I miss it.

Comment: This actually does not answer the question, but solves the problem. :) I upvoted it anyway.

Comment: @DejanLekic True. As soon, as the answer comes, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[DUB package of DUB](http://code.dlang.org/packages/dub) is good for you.

---

It contains *first hand* library code it takes to

- load,
- manipulate and
- save

packages (be it in SDL or JSON format).

---

Of course you've got to get your hand dirty to do the appropriate plumbing (writing a `package converter command line utility` in your case for instance).